# Braintree PayPal checkout component throwing "e.client.getVersion is not a function"

Tags: javascript, paypal, braintree

I'm struggling to understand what I'm doing wrong here:

```
 braintree.client.create({
     authorization: res.clientToken // this is the token, I know it is correct
 }, (err, client) => {
    if (err) { ... }
    braintree.paypalCheckout.create({ client }, (err, paypalInstance) => {
        if (...) { ... }
    })
 });
```

When calling `braintree.paypalCheckout.create`, an error is called synchronously:

> Uncaught TypeError: `e.client.getVersion` is not a function

Indeed, the `client` object doesn't have such a method. I followed the code from [this page](https://braintree.github.io/braintree-web/current/module-braintree-web_paypal-checkout.html#.create) and [this page](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/checkout-with-paypal/javascript/v3) (pretty much the same thing).

How to fix the problem? The PayPal Checkout component is loaded and appended to the `braintree` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

[`getVersion`](https://braintree.github.io/braintree-web/current/Client.html#getVersion) is a method of the `client` class [as of version 3.16.0](https://github.com/braintree/braintree-web/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#3160) of `braintree-web`. Update the version of [`braintree-web`](https://github.com/braintree/braintree-web) you're using to 3.16.0+.

Comment: Yes, I think I was using `3.9.x`. Thank you!

Comment: I'm getting e.getVersion is not a function on using data-collector.min.js using version 3.25.0.  Is this related?

Comment: I am using version 3.31.0, and i am getting the same error?

Comment: 2 and a half years later and I'm getting the same error with 3.65.0 using the Dropin UI

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this when trying to use `vaultManager` in conjunction with `dropIn`.

Now I'm not *actually* planning on continuing with that - I'm just playing. Looks like I'm going to have to go fully custom - hence why I wanted to start playing with `vaultManager`.

Anyway I had this :

```
 braintree.dropin.create({....}, (err, instance) => {

       braintree.vaultManager.create({ client: instance }, (e, vmInstance) =>
       {
           vmInstance.fetchPaymentMethods((err, paymentMethods) => {

              alert(JSON.stringify(paymentMethods)); 
           });
       });
 });
```

Turns out `instance` is NOT a `Client` object. It is a `Dropin` object ;-) It creates its own client stored on `_client` private property.

I needed instead to do `braintree.client.create(...)` to get a true `Client` object.

I actually cheated and did this - just for the time being:

```
 braintree.vaultManager.create({ client: instance._client },
```

Like I said I don't recommend using both DropIn and Vault together, it kind of defeats the point of both.